# Watir: errors when the browser is not in focus

Tags: ruby, watir

I use Ruby/Watir to test login/logout to a website. My simple code:

```
@b.goto 'website_address'
@b.text_field(:id => USR_NAME_FLD).set username
@b.text_field(:id => PASSWORD_FLD).set password
@b.div(:id => LOGIN_BUTTON).click
```

Works well when the browser window is focused or unfocused from the start, but when I change the focus(switch to the other window) during the phase of entering username/password, I receive a username/password mismatch error after trying to log in.

Both fields contain correct values, so the problem should be somewhere else.

Browser instantiation:

```
capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::W3CCapabilities.firefox(accept_insecure_certs: true) 
@b = Watir::Browser.new( :firefox, :desired_capabilities => capabilities)
```

Comment: I dont know why do you want to disturb the test environment or the browser where the tests are getting executed? Does it happen if you open an other window? and do your task? Recommended is that you leave the browser until the tests are over and you don't disturb it

Comment: This issue causes incovenience during the debugging phase, when I run tests from the IDE

Comment: Per the spec it isn't supposed to matter if a window has focus or not - https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#h-note14 While geckodriver is still in beta it is recommended that you use the latest geckodriver & Firefox Nightly versions.

Comment: Hi Titus, 

It is true that the issue is related to geckodriver - I don't have such problems  using chrome. But it is still present even using the latest one.